# Vue.js - disable removeAttributeQuotes for pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js

We need to disable the minify.removeAttributeQuotes property for pages.

This is my **vue.config.js**:

```js
const packageJson = require('./package.json')

module.exports = {
  
  assetsDir: packageJson.name + '/static',

  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete('preload-search')
    config
      .plugin('html-search')
      .tap(args => {
        return [
          {
            preload: false,
            title: packageJson.description,
            template: __dirname + '/public/search.html',
            minify: {
              removeAttributeQuotes: false
            }
          }
        ]
      })
  },

  pluginOptions: {
    i18n: {
      locale: 'de',
      fallbackLocale: 'en',
      localeDir: 'locales',
      enableInSFC: true
    }
  },

  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: 'src/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      title: 'Index Page',
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'index']
    },
    search: {
      entry: 'src/search/main.js',
      template: 'public/search.html',
      filename: 'search.html',
      title: 'Search Page',
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'search']
    }
  }

}
```

We using the **pages**-property for more then one endpoints. Therefore we have to changed the "**plugin('html')**" plugin to "**plugin('html-search')**".

**The problem now is:**

Since we use the pages-property the **public/search.html** will not minified and also no js/css injections are rendered into the file.

**The only thing I do was:**

1. Defined the pages property like https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages.
2. Defined the webpack chaining to configure the html plugin like https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-plugin

I have no more ideas for this problem.

Best regards, 
Mario

Answer (score 0):

Self solved by:

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete('preload-search')
    config
      .plugin('html-search')
      .tap(args => {
        args[0].minify.removeAttributeQuotes = false
        return args
      })
}
```